# Fetch entity with max attribute value as well as in to one relationship using nspredicate

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

For example, my app have tow entity : `Department` <--->> `Employee`. I want to fetch a `employee` object which has max `salary` value in a paticular `department` object. `salary` is a attribute on `Employee`.

I tried the following code :

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"department == %@ && salary == max(salary)", self.department];
```

But no any one object returned.

What's the most efficient and correct way to accomplish this task using nspredicate?

Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should amend the predicate to filter only the department, but then use a sort descriptor to sort the results by salary, descending.  Then set the fetch limit to 1, so you get only the Employee with the highest salary:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Employee"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"department == %@", self.department];
NSSortDescriptor *salarySort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"salary" ascending:NO];
fetch.sortDescriptors = @[salarySort];
fetch.fetchLimit = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, this way should work! But i can't make sure it's the efficient way to do such queries on core data cuz my app have large data sets.

Answer (score 0):

An efficient solution is to just use relationships instead of fetch requests. Core Data optimizes behind the scenes so you need not be afraid of performance or memory issues.

```
Employee *highestPaid = [department.employees sortedArrayUsingSortDescriptors:
  @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"salary" ascending:NO]]].firstObject
```